# What is the command sent by the home button on iPad bluetooth keyboards?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, bluetooth

[The top-left key](http://www.notestostore.com/keyboards/files/ipad-keyboard.jpg) on some bluetooth iPad keyboards functions as a home button. What happens when you connect the keyboard to a regular desktop and push the button, ie, what does the computer see? Is this some sort of command that could be replicated, say with a HID like the Teensy?

Comment: Perhaps I've missed the point, but... I think it isn't possible to connect an iPad keyboard to a desktop computer.  The keyboard connects to the iPad via a dock connector (30 pin, or Lightning for newer models), and this doesn't appear on desktop computers.  Or: what have I missed?

Comment: Whoop I meant bluetooth. Editing accordingly. (Most iPad keyboards are bluetooth.

Comment: Can you provide a keyboard type? The Apple Keyboard does not have such a home-key. Have you tried catching your key codes using third party software? (http://manytricks.com/keycodes/)

Comment: Good question... If VoiceOver is on, the iPad will accept control-option-H to go Home (and command-Tab works for app switching), but I couldn't get this or any key combo to work w/o VoiceOver, using a normal Bluetooth keyboard. If someone has one of those special keyboards, maybe they could try seeing what code is generated when connected to a desktop computer.

Comment: Could somebody try using [the program @the manytricks link](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/) to test a keyboard with a home button and see if it gives any output?

Alternatively try punching the button in question into terminal/cmd and see what it spits out.

Comment: I tried doing that on Many Tricks' Key Codes - the program does not capture output from pressing any key on the first row on the keyboard

Comment: @user1565195 Did you try pressing the function key?

Answer (score 2):

I found a Bluetooth keyboard designed for iPad and other platforms [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00EEMX5DO/ref=noref?ie=UTF8&psc=1&s=computers).  The product pictures show two labels on the top row of keys.

The top left key is labelled with both the "home" roundrect icon and "Esc".

[image: iPad Bluetooth keyboard]

So I think it would be worth trying to send the key code for Escape.

Comment: Sorry for the down vote, but I tested this in the inverse sense (Bluetooth keyboard on iPad), and it is not sending <kbd>Esc</kbd>... Good guess, though.

Comment: On my apple keyboard (sans the home button) that simply sends an escape, which does nothing to the iPad.

Comment: The keyboard might be 'smart' in the way that it knows the difference between a regular computer (esc) or an iPad (home) when sending the key signal using the bluetooth MAC address.

Comment: From the highlighting, it appears that there is a "fn" key on the keyboard that would send the blue command if the "fn" is used as a modifier key.

Comment: @MarkThalman That's a specific keyboard, not what we're looking for. Thanks though.